# Get earliest and latest possible unix timestamps consistent with a given Date

Tags: python, datetime, unix, time, utc

Say that I have a date, e.g. `20 February 2017`, but I have no idea which country/location that date came from. How would I find the earliest and latest unix timestamps consistent with that date?

My naive guess would be the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

# Number of seconds in unix hour
UNIX_HOUR = 3600

# Get midnight unix timestamp for given date
unix_midnight =  int((datetime(2017,2,20)-datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
# Earliest possible timestamp
earliest_timestamp = utc_midnight-14*UNIX_HOUR
# Latest possible timestamp
latest_timestamp = utc_midnight+(24+11)*UNIX_HOUR
```

The minus 14 hours attempts to account for e.g. `Pacific/Kiritimati`, and the plus 11 hours attempts to account for e.g. `Pacific/Niue` in the [IANA timezone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

However, will this always be correct? If these locations have DST (or some other, [even political](https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY), correction) for that date, it could be incorrect. Further, even if I corrected for those particular locations using a library, how do I know that another nearby location without the correction now sets the earliest/latest time?

In other words, are there cases where the above naive code block is incorrect? And if so, does there exist some simple code to detect if/when that is the case?

Comment: You are right that time zones change over time. All of the extreme time zones happen to be only used in tropical countries, so a DST change isn’t likely, but a change like moving a group of islands from -10 to +14 happened in relatively recent times, and it’s not implausible that someone could decide to move to, say, +12 or +12:30 or something in the future.

Comment: Obviously you could just keep a watch on that and update your code if it happens. As an alternative, you could use the `tzdb` library, which automates that—but only if you can trust that all of your users will have up-to-date versions of it. (Which might be fine if “all users” means “our startup’s ops team”, but maybe not so much in the general case.) Or you could write WinAPI code and Linux and Mac code that access the system tzdb, but then you’re relying on the users’ OS being up to date (and limited to whichever platforms you think of).

Comment: Finally, if you really need to be up-to-date no matter what, the only real option is to pull down the tzdb from a known internet location at startup (maybe using a cache with whatever TTL is good enough) and parse it. But even that may not be permanent (IANA’s published page and the most popular version of tzdb have both moved once since being first published).